# Trentrichardson datetimepicker doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I'm trying to use the **[Following timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)**. However, I'm not able to run it. I'm using jsDelivr CDN as suggested by the author.

I include all files listed by the author in the correct order:

- jQuery
- jQuery UI
- datetimepicker
- datetimepicker CSS

  ```
  <!doctype html>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <html>
      <head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui.timepicker.addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
          <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui.timepicker.addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui.timepicker.addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css">

          <script>
              $function () {
              $('#input').datetimepicker();
              });
          </script>

          <title>Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <input type="text" id="input" name="input" value=""/>
      </body>
  </html>
  ```

Nothing displays when clicking on the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0x5xssk/58/)**.

The problem is in the includs the following example will work :

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Example</title>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="input" name="input" value=""/>

        <script>
            $(function () {
                $('#input').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
$function () {
    $('#input').datetimepicker();
});
```

should be

```
$(function () {
    $('#input').datetimepicker();
});
```